# Using JWT with Ktor and including user info in claim

Tags: kotlin, jwt, ktor

I've successfully included a jwt auth token in my application and able to restrict access to the endpoints.  I want to embed the user's ID in the jwt token, but I'm struggling how to implement the jwt verifier in Ktor.

I create a token for the client something like this:

```
val token = JWT.create().withAudience(audience).withIssuer(issuer).withClaim("userId", "XXX").sign(algorithm)
```

The route is setup like this.  The authentication {} block is run on server startup and does not allow creating a verifier with the userId.

This was derived from the jwt sample:

```
route("/api") {
    authentication {
        val jwtVerifier = makeJwtVerifier(issuer, audience)
        jwtAuthentication(jwtVerifier, realm) { credential ->
        if (credential.payload.audience.contains(audience))
            JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
        else
            null
    }

    handle {
       // Handle jwt succcess here
    }
}

private fun makeJwtVerifier(issuer: String, audience: String): JWTVerifier = JWT
        .require(algorithm)
        .withAudience(audience)
        .withIssuer(issuer)
        .build()
```

What is the correct way to do this?  I understand I'd need to create a verifier for each request, but don't really know where to do this nor if that is desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement it in here. You don't need a verifier that checks user ids.

```
jwtAuthentication(jwtVerifier, realm) { credential ->
  if (credential.payload.audience.contains(audience))
    val userId = credential.payload.claims["userId"].asString()
    // check if user exists ... if you want

    JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
  else
    null
}
```

Comment: I get what your suggesting, but how would the verifier work if the token was signed with the userId?  It would require the userId to verify.

Comment: @GaryBak the token is not signed with the user id, the token is signed with the issuing entity's (your service) private key. The user id you're putting in is just one of the "claims" in the token. By the time the verifier code that you write above runs the signature and any expiration dates would have already be verified by `ktor`.

Comment: Thanks @Strelok, after debugging through it a bit I realized that what I had was correct and I had messed up the check for the userId inside my post method.  Your check for the userId above does work.  Thanks for your help.